# use samaccountnames to export user properties(mainly just first name and lastname) to csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file containing the samaccount name of some users.

From this list, I want to export the properties of these users to a CSV file.

Kindly share the simplest possible way to do so in Windows Powershell ISE.

I have tried this :

```
Import-ModuleActiveDirectory

Import-CSV C:\scripts\list.csv | ForEach{Get-ADUser -Identity $samaccountname-Filter*-Properties*|export-csv c:\ADusers.csv

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us the first couple of lines of the CSV file.
A proper CSV file has multiple fields and a header line like this:

> ```
> "AccountName","EmailAddress"
> "doe","john.doe@example.com"
> "kent","clark.kent@example.com"
> ```

If this is the case, do:

```
Import-ModuleActiveDirectory

$userProperties = 'GivenName', 'SurName', 'Initials'
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\List.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.AccountName)'" -Properties $userProperties -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) { 
        $user | Select-Object -Property $userProperties
    }
} | Export-Csv "C:\ADUsers.csv"
```

If the file you load only has SamAccountNames each listed on a new line, then this is not a CSV file and you should use:

```
Import-ModuleActiveDirectory

$userProperties = 'GivenName', 'SurName', 'Initials'
Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\List.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties $userProperties -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) { 
        $user | Select-Object -Property $userProperties
    }
} | Export-Csv "C:\ADUsers.csv"
```

As you can see, I'm not using the `-Identity` parameter here, because in case a user with that SamAccountName is not found, an exception is thrown.
This way, output is only generated when the user actually exists.

Also, it is a **bad** idea to use `-Properties *` when you only want some of the properties returned.

Hope that helps

Comment: in the csv I had only 1 column, the samaccountnames, how is it not a csv file if the format is .csv ?

Comment: @DavidKent A 'proper' csv file has 1 or more columns, and these columns have headers. A csv file is also a text file, but in case there is only one column of data **without** a header, it is much more efficient to use the `Get-Content` cmdlet instead of `Import-Csv -Header 'Something'`

Answer (score 1):

[Vasil's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485602/7264739) was useful to what I am trying to do. It doesn't reference the `SamAccountName` data directly out of the table. The `Get-ADUser` command then fails because it can't interpret the table format. You need to use another variable to reference the actual data in the `row.column`.

I am certain that there is a more efficient way to gather the rows together into a table with headers and then export to a csv. That's not what I'm solving so this is as much time as a I can dedicate to answering the original posters question.

```
$table = Import-CSV "C:\files\samaccountname.csv"
$outfile = "C:\files\otherusrprops.csv"

# Write new csv header 
"GivenName,SurName" | Out-File $outFile -Append

# Loop through each row in the imported csv table
ForEach ($row in $table){

    # Debug to show that the $row variable is in table format
    # $row|Format-Table

    # Grab the data from the row in column SamAccountName
    $name = $row.SamAccountName

    # Debug - Will now show just the SamAccountName
    # echo "$name" 

    # Get the properties from user filtered on object properties into new row.
    $newrow = Get-ADUser -Identity $name | Select-Object 'GivenName', 'SurName' 

    # Append the date from the newrow into the output file.
    $newrow.Givenname | Out-File -NoNewline $outFile -Append
    "," | Out-File $outFile -NoNewline -Append
    $newrow.Surname | Out-File $outFile -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do this in the ISE, you probably dont need/want to use oneliner for that.

I would suggest to import the CSV first, and then run foreach.

```
$list = Import-CSV -path $filePath 

$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($name in $list){

    $adUser=Get-ADUser -Identity $name
    $result += $adUser

}
```

From here, you can start thinking of error handling etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
Import-ModuleActiveDirectory
Import-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\List.csv" | Foreach {
  Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Filter * -Properties *
} | Export-CSV "C:\ADUsers.csv"
```

Your code was not working because $samaccountname was empty and blank not containing the username. So I replaced it with the automatic variable $_

Comment: is there any way to only export the first name , last name and initials ???

Answer (score 0):

Put each SamAccountName on its own line in the list file.

Example:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Change list.csv to a text file (list.txt) and try this:

```
$username = Get-Content "C:\scripts\list.txt"
ForEach($user in $username){
Get-ADUser -Identity $user | Select GivenName,Surname,Initials | Export-CSV -Path "C:\ADUsers.csv"
}
```